# What is the probability that the line is not interferred with?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say we have $n$ random lines in the unit square where a random line is chosen by choosing a point on one side and then randomly choosing a point on one of the other three sides.

What is the probability that at least one of the sides never has a random line intersect it after $n$ random lines?

Comment: lines are infinite in math you mean line segments. and depending on how accurate you measure coordinates you can place infinitely ( either countable or uncountable depending on the set of coordinates) many between two sides of a square of any size.

Comment: This is a complete misunderstanding. OP means that each line is specified by two points, one one one of the sides and the other one one of the other sides.

Answer (score 1):

1. If I understand your problem correctly, then your selection process involves choosing a point uniformly at random on the perimeter of the square, then choosing a point on one of the other sides.
2. Note that this is equivalent to simply choosing two different *sides* of the square uniformly at random (rather than two points on the perimeter of the square).
3. Hence if you consider a specific side to be avoided, the probability that a line avoids that side is 1/2. (Note that there are six different lines you might draw, and three of them pass through that side.)
4. And the probability that $n$ lines all avoid that side is $2^{-n}$.
5. If the side to be avoided isn't specified in advance, then the problem is like this. Let $s$ be the number of sides that have been intersected so far.

   - Initially, $s = 0$.
   - After you draw the first line, two of the sides are intersected. Hence $s=2$. The two remaining sides might be avoided.
   - When you draw the second line, it might intersect the same two sides (probability 1/6), one old side and one new side (probability 2/3), or the remaining two new sides (probability 1/6). These cause the state to be $s=2$, $s=3$, and $s=4$, respectively.
   - If $s=4$, you have lost—all sides have been intersected. If $s=2$, you are in the same state as last time. If $s=3$ and you draw another line, you have a 1/2 chance of intersecting the one remaining side ($s=4$) and a 1/2 chance of intersecting two of the already intersected sides ($s=3$ still).
   - Putting this altogether, we can tabulate these probabilities as a Markov chain
     $$M \equiv \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{4}{6} & \frac{1}{6}\\
     0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
     where $M_{i,j}$ is the probability of going from state $s=i$ to state $s=j$. Then the probability of intersecting all four sides by the time you've drawn $n$ lines is $(M^n)_{1,4}$, and the probability of still having at least one side of the square free is $1-(M^n)_{1,4}$.
   - The summary is that your probability of having at least one side with no lines on it after drawing $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ lines looks like:
     $$1, 1, \frac{5}{6}, \frac{102}{216}, \frac{318}{1296}, \ldots$$

Comment: What does M^n mean in this situation?

Comment: It's $n$ copies of the matrix $M$, multiplied together: $M^n \equiv \underbrace{M\times\ldots\times M}_{n\text{ times}}$. The matrix is just a convenient shorthand way of tabulating the probabilities.